# Stop gif decoding in glide

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

I am using glide to load a gif in my android project.
`Glide.with(getActivity()).load(mainDrawable).asGif().into(mainDrawableView);`

This keeps the gif on repeat, how can one stop the gif from looping?

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me. Glide V4

```
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(/*your gif url*/).listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
@Override
public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
    resource.setLoopCount(1);
    resource.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
            //do whatever after specified number of loops complete
        }
    });
    return false;
}}).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Github post](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1065) has a solution to add request listener & stop the animation in onResourceReady() method.
However, this didn't work for me. May be because in my case resource was local. I ended up with following not so bad workaround:

Export still image from Gif using Gimp or Photoshop. Load still image into ImageView when you want to stop animation. Load original Gif when you want to show animation. Of course this workaround is only good enough for small & local files.

Answer (score 0):

setLoopCount in GifDrawable  inside RequestListener

```
import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable.LOOP_INTRINSIC;

Glide.with(context).asGif().listener(getRequest()).load(R.raw.gif_capture).into(imgProgress);
public RequestListener<GifDrawable> getRequest() {
        return new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                resource.setLoopCount(LOOP_INTRINSIC);

                return false;
            }
        };
    }
```